# Localize countries in PrimeFaces Extensions pe:inputPhone dropdown

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Is there any way to change the used language in the above mentioned component dropdown?

adding `lang="DE"` for german language did not work:

```html
    <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6">
                    <h7>Festnetz</h7>
                    <pe:inputPhone id="festnetz" label="Hallo" lang="DE"
                        initialCountry="#{kontakt.countryIsoFestnetz}"
                        value="#{kontakt.festnetz}" formatOnDisplay="true">
                        <p:ajax event="countrySelect"
                            listener="#{kontakt.onCountrySelectFestnetz}" />
                    </pe:inputPhone>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### PrimeFaces Extensions 12.0.2 and up

Since PrimeFaces Extensions 12.0.2 you can use the `localizedCountries` to do so. You can either supply a `Map<String, String>` containing the ISO 2 abbreviation (lower case) (key), and the name (value):

```java
private Map<String, String> localizedCountries;

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    localizedCountries = new HashMap<>();
    localizedCountries.put("nl", "Nederland");
    localizedCountries.put("be", "België");
    localizedCountries.put("de", "Duitsland");
}

// Add getter
```

```html
<pe:inputPhone onlyCountries="nl,be,de"
               localizedCountries="#{bean.localizedCountries}"/>
```

or a JSON string:

```html
<pe:inputPhone onlyCountries="nl,be,de"
               localizedCountries="{'nl':'Nederland','be':'België','de':'Duitsland'}"/>
```

See also:

- https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/983

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. When will primefaces-extensions 12.0.2 be available?

Comment: We are working with Avalon Theme and PrimeFaces Version 11.0.0. Is this a problem? As it seems Extensions 12.0.2 is not compatible, am I right?

Comment: Correct. PrimeFaces Extensions 12.x.x is compatible with PrimeFaces 12.x.x. So you would need to migrate to PrimeFaces 12 if you are not already on it.